# Objective-C: Draw a polygon on a sphere

Tags: xcode, uiview, geometry, draw

i have the coordinates of a polygon in the 2D space [x,y], (eg. 5 points) and i would like to paint the same shape on a sphere/curved plane.

Which is the best way to do it?

e.g.how to implement a custom draw function in an object derived from UIView...

thank you in advance!
Aldo

Comment: your best bet is OpenGL ES .

Comment: I concur. Just do a search for a EAGLView implementation that you can use as a starting point and modify it.

Comment: Thanks! i will search for this and see how can i modify it... :-)